# Integral involving the zeta function

Tags: calculus

What is the solution to the following integral?

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^{ax}-e^{bx}} dx$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order for people to answer your question, it helps for you to give us your ideas on the problem so far. This enables us to answer according to your level.

Comment: That you put "zeta" in the title suggests you already know it can be expressed using the Hurwitz zeta function and gamma function, namely as $(a-b)^{-n}\zeta(n,\frac{a}{a-b})\Gamma(n)$ (assuming wlog $a>b$).

Comment: Where is the $\displaystyle\large\zeta$ ?.

Comment: @FelixMarin Did you see my comment above yours?

Comment: @blue Yes. I saw your comment. I put it because the OP doesn't give any answer about it. Just to put some pressure. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin Why do you want to put "some pressure?"

Comment: @LordSoth I would like to see what the OP comments about the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $0<a<b$. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}dx&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ax}x^n}{1-e^{-(a-b)x}} dx\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-ax-k(a-b)x}x^n dx\\
&=&\Gamma(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{((a-b)k+a)^{n+1}}\\
&=&\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(a-b)^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+\frac{a}{a-b})^{n+1}}\\
&=&\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{(a-b)^{n+1}}\zeta(n+1,\frac{a}{a-b}).
\end{eqnarray}